# Collapsible table view in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

i am trying to build collapsible table view in xcode, then i found one tutorial from [here](http://blog.paxcel.net/blog/expandablecollapsible-table-for-ios/) and the tutorial project can be downloaded from [here](http://blog.paxcel.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/CustomTable.zip).

However the project is implemented in xib, while i am using storyboard. So i tried to transfer the project into storyboard. Because i am very new to ios programming, after few hours struggle, i only manage to make the project error free on storyboard, but i cant make the collapsible working. In fact, my storyboard version is not even showing the collapsible table cells. Here are the steps i do in storyboard.

1. i dragged a table view controller from the object library on to the storyboard
2. I contrl+drag a segue from the tabbarcontroller to the table view controller
3. I created FourthViewController.h and FourthViewController.m, and then copied RootViewController.h and RootViewController.m from the tutorial project to these two files.
4. I drag and copy the sectionView and sectionInfo files from the tutorial project to my project.
5. I go to the table view controller i created in storyboard, then click on the table view, go to the connection inspector, checked both datasource and delegate point to FourthViewController.
6. I also created a new referencing outlet to FourthViewController and choose "View".

I am not very sure where i am wrong. After build and run, i can not see collapsible elements at all. I am a bit desperate. Appreciate your helps.

Comment: You can't add a table view to Xcode unless you somehow obtain its source code and recompile it. Anyway, why would you want to add a table view to Xcode?

Comment: Because in the original project, i saw it was using table view

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the article you posted, but the free Sensible TableView framework offers a very straight forward approach to automatically creating expandable/collapsable sections. Worth checking out. Good luck!